# CSV File To DB2 Database - skip columns - Spring Batch project

Tags: spring, db2, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring batch project where I have to push data from a CSV file into a DB. Managed to implement the batch and the rest, currently the data is being pushed as it should but I wonder if there's anyway to skip some of the columns in the CSV file as some of them are irrelevant.

I did a bit of research but I wasn't able to find an answer, unless I missed something.

Sample of my code below.

```
<bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
            insert into WEBREPORT.RAWREPORT(CLIENT,CLIENTUSER,GPS,EXTENSION) values (:client, :clientuser, :gps, :extension)
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your `FieldSetMapper` which will map structure from one line to your POJO in reader.

Lets say you have:

```
name, surname, email
Mike, Evans, test@test.com
```

And you have model of `Person` with only `name` and `email`. You are not interested in `surname`. Here is `reader` example:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class PersonReader extends FlatFileItemReader<Person> {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        //load file in csvResource variable
        setResource(csvResource);
        setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
                setFieldSetMapper(new PersonFieldSetMapper());
            }
        });
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

And you can define `PersonFieldSetMapper`:

```
@Component
@JobScope
public class PersonFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Person> {

    @Override
    public Person mapFieldSet(final FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindExceptio   
    {
        final Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(fieldSet.readString(0)); // columns are zero based
        person.setEmail(fieldSet.readString(2));

        return person;
    }
}
```

This is for skipping columns, if I understood right this is what you want. If you want to skip rows, it can be done as well and I explained how to skip blank lines for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673524/how-to-skip-blank-lines-in-csv-using-flatfileitemreader-and-chunks/29697941#29697941).

Comment: @user2342259 did you mean to skip row or skip column? Was this answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

if the check for the skip is simple and does not need a database roundtrip, you can use a simple [itemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html#domainItemProcessor), which returns null for skipped items

real simple pseudo code

```
public class SkipProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Foo,Foo>{
    public Foo process(Foo foo) throws Exception {
        //check for a skip
        if(skip(foo)) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

if the skip check is more complex and needs a database roundtrip, you can use the item processor, but the performance (if needed) will suffer

if performance is critical...well then it depends on setup, requirements and your possibilities, i would try it with 2 steps, one step loads cvs into database (without any checks), second steps reads data from database, and the skip check is done with a clever sql JOIN in the SQL for the itemReader