# Spring Batch - Remove Certain Types of Lines From Reader & JSON Parsing

Tags: java, json, spring

What I'm attempting to do here is only read/parse the JSON portion of a file that is structured like this:

```
From: blahblah:blahblah:3:120319123
2015-02-03 20:05:48.4070783443 +0000 UTC
{"id":"daj;flkaj;dl", "body":"dafjelkaf", "morestuff": 
"flakejfl;ka}flkajfl;daf{fad"}

From: blahblah:blahblah:2:120319123
2016-04-03 20:05:48.4070783443 +0000 UTC
{"id":"daj;flkaj;dl", "body":"dafjelkaf", "morestuff": 
"flakejfl;ka}flkajfl;daf{fad"}
```

I was originally planning to use FlatFileItemReader with the JsonLineMapper, but I would first need to discard the useless lines before parsing the Json line.

How can I skip the line that starts with `From:`, the line with the date, and blank line when reading?

Comment: Tip: using `BufferedReader` to read file line by line, then check if line start with `{` then read it into a string, and find the line end with `}` to end your json.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:batch-file] if you're using Java?

Comment: Whoops that was a mis-click on suggestions.My bad, looks like it was already corrected. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the FlatFileItemReader and call

```
setRecordSeparatorPolicy(yourPolicyTOSkipLines);
```

Where `yourPolicyTOSkipLines` is your own implementation of `SimpleRecordSeparatorPolicy`

See the blank lines skipping code 
[How to skip blank lines in CSV using FlatFileItemReader and chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673524/how-to-skip-blank-lines-in-csv-using-flatfileitemreader-and-chunks)

Comment: This looks like it's what I need, I'll accept the answer as soon as I get a chance to implement. Thanks!

Comment: This worked. Created a custom implementation that would return false for end of record if the beginning of the line didn't start with "{" and then in the pre-processor I would remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly more hacky kind of approach would be to use the setComments() method of the FlatFileItemReader. The method requires a String array with comment prefixes. If you add "From:" to that array, it will be skipped.